# Finding the largest prime factor for a given integer

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the largest prime factor for a user inputed number.

So far i've got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int N;
    printf("Enter a positive number: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int divisor = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++){
        if (N % i == 0){
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++){
                if (i % j == 0 && j != i){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                divisor = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", divisor);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Rather than try a different approach, i'm trying to first understand why the above approach doesn't work.

The above code is supposed to iterate all possible prime factors by first checking if a number i is devisable by the user inputed number, then checking if i is a prime, then repeating the whole process to see if there is a bigger prime that could be a factor. It doesn't work however,  <strike>as it always returns the user inputed number, N</strike>  as it sometimes gives a prime factor, most of the time returns N or some other non-prime number.

Comment: *it always returns the user inputed number, N* are you sure? For example with input number `14`, it correctly outputs `7`.

Comment: @ouah thanks for pointing that out. I'm at a loss to explain why as when I try 21, it returns 21 instead of 7.

Comment: Consider what happens in the last iteration of `i` when it equals `N`. It will be very likely that for some small `j` the `divisor` is set to `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++){ // outer loop
    if (N % i == 0){
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++){ // inner loop
            if (i % j == 0 && j != i){
                break;
            }
            else{
            divisor = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the last iteration of outer loop `i` is equal to `N`. Condition `(N % i == 0)` is `true`. We are in the inner loop. For some `j` condition `(i % j == 0 && j != i)` will be `false`. We are in the `else` clause. So, `divisor = N`.

Comment: Good answer, but this can cause a tremendous amount of work if N is huge

Answer (score 2):

```
else {
    divisor = i;
}
```

This is not good. You suppose that this checks if the divisor is indeed a prime, and if it is, and it also divides the input number, then it assigns it to the `divisor` variable. In reality, this is not what happens. Instead, this will assign the current value of `j` to `divisor` whenever it encounters a `j` that is not prime. What you want instead is to check all prime factors of the number in ascending order, then select the last one:

```
puts("Enter a positive integer:");
char buf[128];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
unsigned n = strtoul(buf, NULL, 10);

unsigned d = 2, maxd = 1, orig = n;

while (d <= orig) {
    while (n % d == 0) {
        n /= d;
        maxd = d;
    }

    d++;
}

printf("\n\nMaximal prime factor: %u\n", maxd);
```

Comment: you can run `while (d <= orig)` until `sqrt(orig)+1`

Comment: @0x90 I'd rather not involve floating-point operations into an integer arithmetic task. Of course, what you say is right, but still not.

Comment: Also, some explanation please for the downvote, which is **wrong.**

Comment: I meant what I said is wrong if orig is prime. joining for the question why the downvote?

Comment: @0x90 Ah, I see, OK. Well, I don't see any reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++){
    if(N % i == 0){
        divisor = i;
        while((N/=i) % i == 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to find all divisors of your number until the number itself. (Which is always a divisor of itself). Then to check if the divisor is prime, you try to divide the number for all numbers from 2 to i-1. If you find a divisor, you correctly stop, but if j is not a divisor you say that i is prime (and save it as the greatest divisor).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the inner loop needs some little modification

```
bool isPrimeDivisor = true;
for(int j=2; j<i;j++) {//inner loop
    if(i%j == 0 && j!=i) {
        isPrimeDivisor = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(isPrimeDivisor) divisor = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work backwards with the loop, starting at i = greatest integer less than or equal to N/2. Check if i is a factor, then check if it is prime and if so return it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//function to find factors
    long long int factors(long long a)
    {
        long long int i=1,c=0;
        for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
        {
            if(a%i==0)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    int main()
    { 
        long long int i,k,a,b;
        printf("enter an integer\n");
        scanf("%llu",&k);

        for(i=2;i<=k/2;i++)
        {                   
            if(k%i==0)
            {
                a=factors(i);
                if(a==2)                
                {
                    b=i;
                }   
            }
        }
    printf("\n______%.1llu_______\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

This will give you the largest prime factor of an integer....